# How to handle assets for different Product Flavors

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have the following problem wherein:

1. I have multiple product flavors In my Android project. {Say, Dev and Production}
2. I have a CI in place ,Jenkins to build my projects and make releases to different teams.
3. I have an asset file which is Flavor Specific, but is dependant upon the data that exists on a server. Example a json for a list of companies.
4. This list is different on Dev vs Production.
5. Since this is a huge json, we include it in our assets folder. Downloading this json at runtime will not allow the user to use the app quickly at least the first time.
6. Currently at compile time in Jenkins we wget/download this json and write them to our assets folder. To get the latest assets for that environment/product flavor at compile time.
7. This wget is written as a shell command in my Jenkins. After a successful wget we run the `gradle assembleDev`, repeat step 6 and then `gradle assembleProduction`

Now the problem lies with the fact that I am not comfortable having this wget in Jenkins for 2 reasons.
1) The Environment specific asset/json is not available on developer machines for their local testing, so they need to be aware all the time.
2) The code in Jenkins is obviously not present in my VCS/Git. Which I am not comfortable with.
What could be the possible solutions?
 
PS:- To put things in perspective, I have 22 Product Flavors and 8 such jsons.

Answer (score 0):

In our production setup, we currently parse a Google Sheets document to find variables and write them into our strings.xml file.
So a some-what similar scenario.

We do this in our Gradle build script, that calls a Java class, that then executes the network logic, returns the downloaded data to Gradle, which writes it into the correct strings.xml file.

This means all of our code is present in our git repository and can be handled as such.

I find this to be quite elegant.

Note: We currently don't differentiate between product flavors, but that is easily done with a few extra lines in Gradle.

Comment: Is your java program part of your Android project or runs separately. Can you share some code.